# XSD / XML quote escaping

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I need to create XSD document with restriction so that we only allow the following values in the XML element.

```
3"
30"
5" x 18"
4" X 12"
Other
```

I started creating an element with restriction with enumeration but I do not know how to specify quotes in the enumeration.
I tried adding restriction with `&quote;`, `'"'`, `\"` but nothing is working.

```
<xs:element name="Diameter">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="3&quote;" />
      <xs:enumeration value="30&quote;" />
      <xs:enumeration value="5&quote; x 18&quote;" />
      <xs:enumeration value="4&quote; x 12&quote;" />
      <xs:enumeration value="other" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&quot;`, not `&quote;`

Alternatively, use `'` ... `'` to deliminate the attribute values, then `"` internally:

```
  <xs:enumeration value='3"' />
```